# WinUI (Win32 and UWP) lags in resizing

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, window-resize, winui

I have a problem with a lag during WinUI application window resizing. I tried both Win32 and UWP options and in both cases, the redraw of the background is lagging and white borders show up. Also, the NavigationView menu elements (Settings icon in particular) are refreshed slowly.

I found this problem described here: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/2506, however, when I tried UWP XAML application the slow refresh of the icons is still present even though the background seems to be refreshed properly.

Just for tests, I run "XAML Controls Gallery" app with a NavigationView menu and there is no problem with a refresh during window resize. The resize is significantly smoother than with all apps I tested.

Now I wonder what type of app is "XAML Controls Gallery"? What may be the problem with my app (in all cases it is just a template app with NavigationView)? Is there some setting for GPU acceleration that needs to be set?

Comment: Do you have reproducing code?

Comment: XAML Controls Gallery isn't using WinUI 3 - WinUI is a bit of a departure. If you want perfectly pleasant Window resizing, sticking with vanilla UWP / WinUI 2.4 will get you that.

Answer (score 0):

XAML Controls Gallery is an uwp type app. After my test, the uwp project hasn’t redraw lag you mentioned. You could create a new blank app like the picture below to test it.

This issue might be related to the WinUI 3 library, I suggest you could report this WinUI 3 issue with GitHub.

[image]